# How do I complete the Cursed Captives achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The Cursed Captives achievement says to free 6 prisoners in 120 seconds in the Cursed Hold (which is obviously Act I).

I have tried this several times and always been quite over 2 minutes. The distance just seems too great to cover in so little time, especially if you get some really annoying champions like wallers or jailers.

Do I need to just hope for a better pseudo-random layout and prisoner placement? Do I need to boost my movement speed as much as possible and just gun it? Would this be easier with any specific class? Is this possible on multiplayer and, if so, is that perhaps the only way to complete this achievement? In short, how do I get this achievement?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but maybe you could clean up everything before you rescue any of the prisoners, and then just run around and Collect Them All. Whether this works depend on how timing is done for this achievement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waiting for an ideal random placement is part of it (I was fortunate enough to have 4 prisoners located nearly adjacent to each other. A pity it took me so long to find them!), but the other thing is that *you don't have to kill everything on your way*.

Speed is of the essence, so skip combat when you can. Abuse the crap outta Dashing Strike and/or Tempest Rush (You're playing a Monk, right?) (Or whatever movement skill your class has) to get in, get out, and keep going.

And lastly, don't give up if it takes a few goes. One run the random numbers will fall into your favor, and then you'll get it in the end.

Comment: Obviously I wasn't ever fighting the enemies unless I had to and that was just until they got with with knockback and I could move past them. The movement skill advice was the most helpful bit (although I find the distances traveled by Dashing Strike to be inconsistent - perhaps because I'm using it wrong?). I did get it not long after your answer and it really does depend on map layout and not running into waller or jailer champions.

Comment: What about if you do it in a party, and go separate ways? Does this count towards the achievement and can it be gained in this way?

Comment: @ickleislands that should work (since quest objectives are shared between players and updated regardless of distance), though I can't verify it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could always wait till your level 60, use the movement passive skill and use mantra of conviction with submission runes. Aided with + movement items works well for that and the timed run a achievements. The mantra on normal difficulty takes care of everything besides bosses in a second at level 60. With a good damage boss' only take a few seconds.